# If $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$, then are $ \{A_i\}^n_{i=1}$ mutually independent?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

So I think the statement is true because:

$\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)$ (From question)

$P(A_n) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(A_i)$

$P(A_n) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i)$ (From question)

However, $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i)$ must be $\leq 0$ since we are adding another event to the intersection.

Since $P(A_n) \geq 0$, $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i)$ must also be $\geq 0$.

So $P(A_n) = 0$.

Since we know a priori, without any dependence on the values of $P(A_i)$, that $P(A_n)=0$. We can say $A_n$ independent of the rest of the events.

We can prove by induction that all events in the set must have probability 0 if the first clause is true.

Is there any mistake in this proof/things I haven't considered in the argument?

This is not a current homework question but was one that had already been graded.

Another thing to note is that it was specified that n > 1.

Thanks!

Comment: It dont seem to be independent. For $n=2$ we have that $\Pr[A\cap B]=\Pr[A]+\Pr[B]$ what is not necessarily equal to $\Pr[A]\Pr[B]$.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean..if Pr[A∩B]=Pr[A]+Pr[B], that means P(A U B) = 0, which means both events have probability 0. So they must be mutually independent right?

Comment: Yes. So to confirm, you are agreeing with me that the statement above is true?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111658/if-pa-0-is-a-a-null-event/111664
A and B don't necessarily have to be the null event if they have probability 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45390/discussion-between-anubhavashok-and-masacroso).

Comment: You are right about the empty set, I deleted my wrong comments. Anyway if the definition of mutually independent events is $\prod \Pr[A_j]=\Pr[\bigcap A_j]$ then it is not necessarily true that $\prod\Pr[A_j]=\sum\Pr[ A_j]$. Why you assume that $P(A_n) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(A_i)$? The statement is true for $\Pr[\bigcap_j^{n} A_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\Pr[A_j]$, but it doesnt mean that $\Pr[\bigcap_j^{n-1} A_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\Pr[A_j]$ is true.

Comment: If you read the question again, I said: "We can prove by induction that all events in the set must have probability 0 if the first clause is true.". Since the question stated n>1, we can consider the case that n = 2 as a base case. We have actually already proved the case for n=2 in our first 2 comments.

Comment: Oh, ok... so we have that $\Pr[\bigcap_j^{n-1} A_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\Pr[A_j]$ is true by assumption. Then yes, if you can prove by induction the same for all the other probabilities then it is right. But, are you sure that this hold for all the other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is correct but your proof is not. The statement is only for a fixed $n$ (at least the way it is written). So the assertion in the third line for $n-1$ is not a consequence of the hypothesis in the statement.

A suggestion: If $n=1$ then there is nothing to show. So let $n>1$. We want to show that every $P(A_k)=0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. So let $j\neq k$, $1\leq j\leq n$. Then

$$ P(A_j)\leq P(A_j) + P(A_k) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)= P (\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq P(A_j)$$
which implies equality at all places. But then from the first we see that $P(A_k)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate the elegance of the proof you provided.
Yes, I was aware of the assertion for n-1, which is why I stated: "We can prove by induction that all events in the set must have probability 0 if the first clause is true". The proof for the base case of n=2 was not mentioned explicitly, but was discussed in the comments.